# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input must be set

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, automation

Im using intelliJ IDEA for my automation. My code works perfectly fine before i added TestNG 7.8 and jcommander 1.7 in my dependencies and now it does not work.

[Mainform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaHuw.png)This is my Mainform

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(50));
        driver.get("https://demo.seleniumeasy.com/");

// Single Checkbox Demo
        SingleCheckBoxDemo SingleCheckBoxDemo = new SingleCheckBoxDemo(driver);
        SingleCheckBoxDemo.SingleCheckBoxDemoStart();
        SingleCheckBoxDemo.SingleCheckBoxDemoDemo();
        SingleCheckBoxDemo.SingleCheckBoxDemoClose("SingleCheckBoxDemo Validation Completed");

    }
}
```

[SingleCheckBoxForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfIG5.png)Here is my SingleCheckBox class

```
public class SingleCheckBoxDemo extends AbstractObjectsUsed{
    WebDriver driver;

    public SingleCheckBoxDemo(WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
    }
    public void SingleCheckBoxDemoStart() {
        InputFormLink.click();
        CheckBoxLink.click();
    }
    public void SingleCheckBoxDemoDemo() {
        CheckBox1.click();
        waitForElementToAppear(VerificationMessage);
        System.out.println(SuccessMessage);
    }
    public void SingleCheckBoxDemoClose(String Validation) {
        System.out.println(Validation);
    }
}
```

[Waituntilexpectedcondition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ix9h.png)Here is where the problem

```
public class AbstractObjectsUsed {
    WebDriver driver;
    public AbstractObjectsUsed(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
    }
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(50));
    public void waitForElementToAppear(By findBy)
    {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(findBy));
    }
```

[Input Must be set error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XznEO.png)this is the output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input must be set
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require.nonNull(Require.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:43)
    at org.example.AbstractObjectsUsed.<init>(AbstractObjectsUsed.java:18)
    at org.example.SingleCheckBoxDemo.<init>(SingleCheckBoxDemo.java:16)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/errors. Please instead post them as text and use a [code block] to format it.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/51627/java-maven-illegalargumentexception-input-must-be-set)?

Comment: Hello guys sorry first time ive edited my question pls help